# javaScript in blade template laravel I have a image slider that works on my php website. However when I put the exact code on a blade doesnt work

Tags: javascript, laravel

the java Script code works on a php page. What must I do to get it to work in laravel on a blade template. how can I do  this. It appears the JavaScript is not working.I am not sure what the problem is.

```
<script  src="{{url('js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')}}"></script>
<script  src="{{url('js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js')}}"></script>
<script  src="{{url('js/jHtmlArea-0.7.5.js')}}"></script>
<script  src="{{url('jquery.center.min.js')}}"></script>
<script  src="{{url('js/jquery.printElement.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/jquery.backstretch.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/jquery.highlight-3.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/main.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideshowx > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshowx > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshowx');
    $('.grid').masonry('layout');
    },  4000);
});
</script>
<STYLE>
</STYLE>
<?php 
$number=1; 
echo "<DIV ID='slideshowx' STYLE='margin:0px auto;position:relative;width:100%;max-  width:540px;padding:0px;border:0px solid #00ff00;'>";
echo "<IMG SRC='images/blank.png' BORDER=0 STYLE='width:100%;border-radius:5px;border:0px solid #AAAAAA;object-fit:fill;'>";
//echo "<DIV STYLE='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;border-radius:5px;width:100%;max-width:540px;'><IMG SRC='images/mobilefriendly2.png?t=".time()."' BORDER=0 STYLE='width:100%;max-width:540px;border-radius:5px;border:0px solid #262938;'></DIV>";
$pixs = array_diff(scandir("pixs"), array('..', '.'));
foreach($pixs as $key => $src){
    echo "<DIV STYLE='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;border-radius:5px;width:100%;max-width:540px;border:0px solid #00FF00;overflow:hidden;'>";
    echo "<IMG SRC='pixs/".$src."?t=".time()."' BORDER=0 STYLE='width:100%;border-radius:5/px;border:0px solid #AAAAAA;object-fit:fill;'>";
    if ($number % 2 == 0)
    //echo "<IMG SRC='images/3uiitte.png' BORDER=0 STYLE='width:100%;object-fit:fill;border-radius:5px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;border:0px solid #DDDDDD;'>";
    //else
    //echo "<IMG SRC='images/4uiitte.png' BORDER=0 STYLE='width:100%;object-fit:fill;border-      radius:5px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;border:0px solid #DDDDDD;'>";
    $number++;      
    echo "</DIV>";
    
}   
print_r($pixs);
echo "</DIV>";
echo "</DIV></DIV>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script block you're loading jQuery first :

```
<script  src="{{url('js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')}}"></script>
```

and then a different version last :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pick one version and load it before loading all other scripts that depend on it. Because you're loading it twice, all scripts loaded before you load it the second time won't work.